# Repeat loop until function input changes

Tags: python, loops, audio

I have a piece of python code that generates a continuous stream of values. I need these values to be translated into audio feedback in the form of a buzzer of which the pause duration between beeps is related to the stream of values.

I have another piece of python code that generates a continuous beep with a certain pause duration (see below).

How can I repeat this piece of code (i.e. repeat the same beep with the same pause duration) UNTIL the input pause value changes, i.e. until I call the function again with a new value for 'pause'?

EDIT - after a suggestion by a commentor I've updated the code to put it into a class. How to make this class responsive to new input? I'd love some assistance as I'm not very comfortable with classes.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import time 
from threading import Thread

f = 440.0
duration = 0.25 
volume=0.5
fs=44100
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
        channels=1,
        rate=fs,
        output=True)

class beeper(Thread): 
    def __init__(self, pause):
        self.pause = pause

    def beep(self, pause2):
        samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

        print('1')
        while True:
            if pause2 == self.pause:
                stream.write(volume*samples)
                time.sleep(self.pause)
                print('2')
            else:
                stream.write(volume*samples)
                time.sleep(pause2)
                self.pause = pause2
                print('3')

    def stop(self):
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()
```

I want the beep to repeat until the function is called again with a new and different value for 'pause'.

It now just repeats indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

lazy way would be a global variable, but that would be a bad way. A better way would be to put the beeper into a class with a variable that saves the value for pause during init, then check the value of the beeper during calling it.

Comment: Could you help me a bit with working this into a class? I've never worked with classes before...

Comment: Bernard, I've attempted to put it into a class and replaced the code in my original posting.